# How to insert data to HTML page with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data and I would like to write it into an HTML page.
In PHP in would be possible just to write

```
<?php   .... take the data and print it ?>
```

How can it be done with Python?

Should I generate the WHOLE page with Python or can I just extract this data and place it in the needed place in the HTML page?

This should be accessed from a web server when someone requests a URL.

Comment: How will this python program be used? On a webserver, when someone accesses a URL, or as a script to batch edit HTML files?

Comment: on a server when user asks for URL

Comment: Use a web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or Django. You specify the HTML in a template and then render the data out to it from your python script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), you can use templates to render data into HTML without having to print out the entire HTML from Python (actually, it does that behind-the-scenes, but you only have to write your template once).

Flask uses a templating language called Jinja2, which lets you write templates like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         Hello, {{ name }}.
    </body>
</html>
```

and render them out like this:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    title = "My Page"
    name = "Foo"
    return render_template('mytemplate', title=title, name=name)
```

Django has a similar function with its inbuilt templating system.

If you are running on a cheap webhost, you might not have the flexibility for running a full-blown web framework like Django or Flask (which have a lot of dependencies and should be run in a WSGI server). On my webhost, Siteground, I use a microframework called [Bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), which is similar to Flask but has only a single-file dependency so it can run wherever Python is running, using CGI. I have it set up as detailed in [this post](http://introspection.net.au/2015/07/29/python-on-siteground), by running it as CGI—`app.run(server='cgi')`—and use .htaccess rules with mod_rewrite to remove the `app.py` from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/

Do like this:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Обработка данных форм</title>
        </head>
        <body>""")

print("<h1>Обработка данных форм!</h1>")
print("<p>TEXT_1: {}</p>".format(text1))
print("<p>TEXT_2: {}</p>".format(text2))

print("""</body>
        </html>""")
```

Comment: Thanks @viktor.svirskyy this would be actually writing the WHOLE page in python. I wouldn't want to do it and this is what I ask - is it possible to write ONLY the data?

Comment: Best practice use http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/ or another templating language

Answer (score -1):

You can push the data to mysql and fetch that using php code.

[python code for pushing to mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp)

[php code for fetching from mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)